# how to insert list resulted from bs4 into databse?

Tags: mysql, database, beautifulsoup, mysql-connector

I was trying to insert all list of crawling data into database. I have connected to the database successfully but no data appear in the database table.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import errorcode


urls2 = []
result = requests.get("http://desaku.bandungkab.go.id/desaonline/")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('a')
urls = []
for link in links:
    if "www" in link.text:
        url = link.attrs['href']
        urls.append(url)


num1=len(urls)
b=0
while b<10:
    result2 = requests.get(urls[b])
    src2 = result2.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src2, 'lxml')
    links2 = soup.find_all('a')

    for link in links2:

        if "selengkapnya" in link.text:
            url2 = link.attrs['href']
            urls2.append(url2)
    b+=1

konten = []
num=len(urls2)
i=0
while i<num:
    result3 = requests.get(urls2[i])
    src3 = result3.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src3, 'lxml')
    res = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'teks'})
    for link in res:
        links3 = link.find_all('p')
        konten.append(links3)
    i+=1

judul = []
num=len(urls2)
i=0
while i<num:
    result3 = requests.get(urls2[i])
    src3 = result3.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src3, 'lxml')
    res2 = soup.find('h2', attrs={'class':'judul'})
    judul.append(res2)
    print(judul)
    i+=1

tanggal = []
num=len(urls2)
i=0
while i<num:
    result3 = requests.get(urls2[i])
    src3 = result3.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src3, 'lxml')
    res3 = soup.find_all('h3', attrs={'class':'kecil'})
    for link in res3:
        links4 =
```

link.find('i').next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.replace('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', '')
            tanggal.append(links4)
        print(tanggal)
        i+=1

```
try:
   connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                             database='bs4-test',
                             user='root',
                             password='')
   sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO `artikel`
                      (`judul`, `tanggal`, `konten`) VALUES (judul, 
tanggal, konten)"""
   cursor = connection.cursor()
   result  = cursor.execute(sql_insert_query)
   connection.commit()
   print ("Record inserted successfully into table")
except mysql.connector.Error as error :
    connection.rollback() #rollback if any exception occured
    print("Failed inserting record into  table {}".format(error))
 finally:
    #closing database connection.
    if(connection.is_connected()):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

I want to insert list of judul, tanggal, and konten into database.

Comment: Your question is unnecessarily long and convoluted; pear it down ruthlesslly (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As to your actual question, please post one example of `urls2[i]`.

Comment: urls2 is a list of links that bring you directly to every article in the website. I put "i" in the bracket because i want to access every link 1 by 1 based on the position on the list. here are example of urls2:

['http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/423', 'http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/421', 'http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/420', 'http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/419', 'http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/414', 'http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/413', 'http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/412' ]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simplified version of your code using only one of your articles. You'll have to modify it for your loop, but -if I understand correctly what your are looking for - it should get you started, I believe:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = 'http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/423'
result = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(result.content, 'lxml')

konten = []
kons = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'teks'})
for kon in kons:
    link= kon.find_all('p')
    konten.append(link)

judul = []
jud = soup.find('h2', attrs={'class':'judul'})
judul.append(jud)

tanggal = []
tangs = soup.find_all('h3', attrs={'class':'kecil'})
for tang in tangs:
    tanggal.append(tang.text.replace('\t','sep').split('sep')[3])

print(konten)
print(judul)
print(tanggal)
```

Output:

```
[[<p>Hari Jum'at Tanggal 28 Desember 2018 dilaksanakan Pendistribusian/Pembagian  Beras BPNT (Bantuan Pangan Non Tunai) oleh BUMDES (Badan Usaha Milik Desa) Mekar Lestari di Desa Ancolmekar bagi masyarakat yang memiliki Kartu BPNT.</p>]]
[<h2 class="judul">PENDISTRIBUSIAN BERAS BPNT BULAN DESEMBER</h2>]
['02 Januari 2019 09:46:46']
```